# How to convert ASCII to ISO-8859-1 in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii, data-conversion, iso-8859-1

I'm currently trying to figure out how to convert an **ASCII** encoded string to **ISO-8859-1** encoding to be used for `utf8_encode()` to display special characters like "**ñ**" but I can't seem to make it work. In need of help.

I've already tried this `iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "ISO-8859-1", $text);` and this `mb_convert_encoding($text, "ISO-8859-1");` and also this `mb_convert_encoding($text, "ASCII", "ISO-8859-1");` but it doesn't work, the string is still ASCII encoded.

I've created a temporary solution for this by creating a lookup table using the string provided by reading each character of the string. But I want to use the php built-in functions, is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function convertString($text) {

    $text = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "ISO-8859-1", $text);
    echo mb_detect_encoding($text) .'<br/>'; // to check what encoding the string is in, displays ASCII
    return utf8_encode($text);

}

echo convertString('\xc3\xb1');

?>
```

Comment: Why not just go from ASCII to UTF-8? There are only 256 characters in ASCII anyway, most of which are the same as the equivalent characters in the UTF-8 character set anyway...

Comment: HI @CD001, I already tried ASCII to UTF-8, but the conversion just doesn't work. The string still remains as ASCII

Comment: `convertString('\xc3\xb1')` - you are aware that the value you are passing to the function here does _not_ represent an `ñ`, right? If not, you need to go read up on same basics first of all, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Hi @misorude, I am aware that it needs to be a double-quoted string to be an `ñ`, but what if the string came from the database? That's why I am trying to make a 
string converter for UTF-8 codes.

Comment: _“but what if the string came from the database?”_ - then it is still a major difference whether you have an _actual_ `ñ`, or a sequence of characters that are supposed to _represent it_ in some form of meta encoding … Are you planing on making these conversions on the fly all the time, when you output the content? I think converting the database to contain proper UTF-8 to begin with might make more sense.

Comment: @misorude, you're right, but I'm currently not in a position where I can make changes like that. Thanks by the way!

Comment: @NewbinGlasses You only need to detect (guess) a character encoding if you have lost data: specifically, which character encoding produced the bytes. When guessing, there are always many possible answers. `mb_detect_encoding` gives just one, though it lets you give a priority list for which one answer you'd like.